# decompressing special rle - imageproc

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am trying to decompress an rle file which was compressed in special way .
I am getting back an image which is differenet then the original and I can't understand why.
1st Ill explain the way it was compressed :
the original Image is gray image with only 2 kind of pixels in it : White Or Black . 
in the compression they used a byte to represent each sequence of pixels .
the MSB bit in each byte represent White(=1) or Black(=0) . the other 7 Bit represent the sequence so it can be maximum value of 127 . 
for example 127 pixels of white will be : 11111111B => 255 DEC.
also 127DEC will represent 127 pixels of black (MSB is 0).
the original Image is 120x240 BMP and I am using a known function (it was given to me) to save BMP files so there is no problem in the saving of array to bmp files if all the rules were followed .
Also in the compressed file the first 2 BYTE will represent the arraysize . arraysize = rle[0]*256 + rle[1].

I'll put here only the part the decompress and compress ( I built them both)

```
void RleDeCompress(unsigned char rleimage[2 + 240 * 120], unsigned char decompressedimage[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{
// 1st MSB bit from the 8 bit of each cell in the array represent color - Black or White
//2nd~7th BIT represent the number of times the color repeats itself
// first 2 cells in the array are represent the size of the array



int arraysize = rleimage[0] * 256 + rleimage[1];
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
unsigned char colormask = 128; //binary 10000000=128dec
unsigned char multiplymask = 127; // binary 01111111 = 127dec

unsigned int total = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < arraysize+2; i++)
{
    unsigned char blackorwhitebinary = (rleimage[i] & colormask) >> 7 ; // mask only the msb and then shift it to be the lsb
    unsigned char color = 255 * blackorwhitebinary; // decide if this is black or white 
    unsigned char multiply = rleimage[i] & multiplymask; // number of times the color repeats itself



    for (int j = 0; j < multiply; j++)
    {
        decompressedimage[row][col] = color;
        col++;
        if (col == NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
        {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }

        if (row > NUMBER_OF_ROWS) cout << "error too many rows " << endl;

    }


    total += multiply;
    // check total of cells real in the binary file



}

cout << "total is:" << total << endl;



}








void RleCompress(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], unsigned char RleImage[2 + 240 * 120])
{
    unsigned char n = 0;
unsigned int N = 2;
unsigned int arrsize=0;
unsigned char temparray[ 240 * 120];
for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
    {
        temparray[arrsize] = image[row][column] / 255;
        arrsize++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
{
    n++;
    if (n == 127)
    {
        RleImage[N+2] = temparray[i] * 128 + n;
        n = 0;
        N++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (i == arrsize)
        {
            RleImage[N + 2] = temparray[i] * 128 + n;
        }
        else
        {
            if (temparray[i] != temparray[i + 1])
            {
                RleImage[N + 2] = temparray[i] * 128 + n;
                n = 0;
                N++;
            }
        }
    }
}
RleImage[0] = N / 256;
RleImage[1] = N % 256;
}




void SaveRleFile(unsigned char RleImage[2 + 240 * 120])
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("P01C.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 2 + 120 * 240)
    {
        myfile << RleImage[index];
        index++;
    }
    cout << "index is :" << index << endl;
}

myfile.close();

}






void LoadRleBinFile(char binfilename[], unsigned char * image)
{
//for (int j = 0; j < 2 + 120 * 240; j++) image[j] = 255; //clears the array from garbage and sets all of it to white.

ifstream myfile;
char c;
int i = 0;
myfile.open(binfilename, ios::in | ios::binary); // open file in binary mode input only
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile.get(c);
        image[i] = (unsigned char) c;
        i++;


    }
}
else
    cout << "error while opening file " << endl;


myfile.close();
}

void main()
{

unsigned char GrayImage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char Rlearray[2 + 240 * 120]; //rlearray size is unknown  when first initialzing . worst case is 2 + 240*120
 LoadGrayImageFromTrueColorBmpFile(GrayImage, "P01A.bmp");
 StoreGrayImageAsGrayBmpFile(GrayImage, "P01B.bmp");
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ConvertGrayImageToBlackWhite(GrayImage);
 StoreGrayImageAsGrayBmpFile(GrayImage, "P01B2.bmp");

 RleCompress(GrayImage, Rlearray);
 SaveRleFile(Rlearray);
LoadRleBinFile("P01C.rle", Rlearray);
RleDeCompress(Rlearray, GrayImage);
StoreGrayImageAsGrayBmpFile(GrayImage, "P01C.BMP");

//WaitForUserPressKey();
}
```

I found a way to check that there is a problem and it's in the code .
the number of pixels in the picture (120*240 =28800 )should be ,or atleast thats what seems most logic to me , equal to the sum of all the sequence because if not then we didn't compressed the whole image. 
In my code the sum of all the sequences is about 17000 . != 28800 .
I don't understand if I didn't compressed right or didnt decompressed right but from looking on the binary file (with binary viewer program) it seems the binary rle file is ok .

Comment: Try creating an all-black image and seeing if it encodes correctly, then if it decodes. Then try an all-white image. Then try a checkerboard. Use your debugger.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thx man great tip . I spent hours trying to finding my errors and with trying to run it on only white image I manged to correct it in 20 minutes . cheers

Comment: Well done! Good luck with your project!